# Why is WPML creating multiple file entries after saving

Tags: wpml

I have a Wordpress installation using WPML, ACF, and Custom Post Types. When I save a new entry for any custom post-type (also for Page) it is saving it as 2 or more entries. When I erase one of those entries, all of them are gone. When I try to remove them permanently from the trash, I get an error message.

Whenever I save a post I have two (or more entries) with the same title. When I want to delete it, it gives me this error:

```
Warning: mysqli_query(): (21000/1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row 
in /wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2056 
WordPress database error: [Subquery returns more than 1 row] 
SELECT translation_id FROM wp_icl_translations WHERE trid = 
    (SELECT trid FROM wp_icl_translations 
        WHERE element_id=3596 AND element_type='post_people')
```

When I do a translation into Spanish and save it - there are 3-6 posts in Spanish with the same title.

I tried with the WPML Form. Reinstalling all the plugins again. Reset things in the troubleshooting page. We have around 1000 entries and now we run into this problem.

Any idea where it could have gone wrong and how to solve it?

Comment: What exactly is wrong? What's the error message? What is `WPML Form`? You need to make your question more focused.

Comment: Whenever I save a post I have two (or more entries) with the same title. When I want to delete it, it gives me this error:

--
Warning: mysqli_query(): (21000/1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row in /www/htdocs/w01b9d11/ikg.institute/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2056
WordPress database error: [Subquery returns more than 1 row]
SELECT translation_id FROM wp_icl_translations WHERE trid = (SELECT trid FROM wp_icl_translations WHERE element_id=3596 AND element_type='post_people')
---

When I do a translation into spanish and save it - there are 3-6 posts in spanish with the same title